# Do "filter courses" really filter out "weak" students from subsequent courses?

Tags: mathematics, curriculum

My department (of mathematical sciences in a US university) is considering some curriculum changes for our majors and the topic of our "mathematical filter course" came up.

For clarity, I'll define a mathematical filter course as a course that is treated as a pre-requisite for other courses but whose content isn't really necessary for those subsequent courses (though in a general sense does make sense to include in the major). The intention being that such a course would help to filter out weaker students who might be interested in those subsequent courses (and potentially one of our majors), but lack either the drive or skill in mathematical thinking to really do well in those courses (and the major). In the past, we used calculus as such a filter, but for our Applied Data Science major we are considering using an applied linear algebra course instead.

While on the surface, the idea makes sense to me (though I don't have a sense of how common such a "filter" course comes up in other schools/programs/fields of study), the conversation left me wondering:

Do filter courses really do what they set out to do and distill the population of students going on to the next course and the rest of the program (or more specifically, do they distill *enough* to be worthwhile)? or would including such a course in a major's curriculum potentially be a waste of valuable course time that could be better utilized elsewhere in the program?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136174/discussion-on-question-by-vindel-do-filter-courses-work-well-in-mathematics).

Comment: Thanks to pedroelpanda, Squary94, and Ben for wonderful answers; my understanding on filter courses is greatly enriched by your responses. It is clear that the idea of a filter course is far more layered than I first imagined, but there are some clear takeaways for me, 1) arbitrarily hard courses are a bad idea, 2) filter courses should be motivated by protecting students from going too far down a path that ultimately is not a good fit for them,  and 3) a filter should still be relevant even if not necessarily direct content-wise for subsequent courses, giving a clear sense of future courses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you mean "filter" courses in the way that some in the US also use the phrase "weed-out" courses, i.e., an artificially difficult introductory course which is designed to decrease the size of the cohort, by scaring away, or failing out, a certain percentage of students.

Generally speaking, "filter" or "weed-out" courses have some benefits and detriments. The benefits are obvious for the department, as they in some way reduce the enrollment in the department's courses, and ensure that those who remain are in some way capable, given that they have already proved themselves in the past.

The detriments can be less obvious. Particularly in mathematics, "filter" courses can foster a toxic environment, and can force students from less traditional backgrounds out of the major. Realistically, students in this linear algebra class who went to private schools or better-funded public schools in the US may have already taken linear algebra in the past. Is everyone on an even playing field? And will this course impact anybody disproportionately? Will a large course with, say, a strict grading curve, foster a competitive environment in which some students will feel discouraged to collaborate with their friends? Are you really selecting for the most talented people, or for people who thrive in a certain environment?

You seem to suggest that some of these "filter" courses are completely auxiliary for the major as a whole, but your example of linear algebra in a data science major says otherwise. As everyone in the comments was quick to point out, linear algebra sounds more like a vital pre-requisite, which may not be directly necessary for most courses in your department, but which most students *should* know. In my experience, most "filter" courses fulfill a similar role. Generally speaking, if your department forces students to take an artificially difficult class which is entirely useless, then the department should not be surprised when a large amount of students do run away from the major.

Anectodally speaking, my mathematics department in undergrad got rid of an intentional weed-out course a few years before I arrived. The overall enrollment in the department went up, to no one's surprise, but so did the percentages of female students, and those belonging to racial minorities (I do have numbers to back up this claim, but once again, only in the context of my department). You may take that as you will, but personally, I would suggest that this is not because such students were weaker, but rather because something about a competitive weed-out course affected them more than it would affect others.

Answer (score 5):

I have witnessed 4 variations of filter courses in Germany and would like to go into each variation of it from a student's perspective.

The first variation I witnessed was artificial difficulty introduced by intentional obfuscation. The materials used for the course were simply read out by the professor and not really explained. Questions were brushed off and not really explained, which discouraged further questions very quickly. The provided materials were lacking which "encouraged" the student to look into other sources, mainly those listed by the professor at the start of the semester. This bred **tremendous** amounts of ill will towards the subject and professor.  Participation rates were low and it did force quite a few students into different majors all in order to circumvent the course. It did indeed filter out weaker students from studying but also prevented quite a few others that simply decided that this is not something worth putting up with.

The second variation I witnessed introduced many assignments to pass as a prerequisite to enter the final exam. This felt like a ton of busy work but overall was not too bad. It was really painful for those that worked a second (or third) job on the side since any time taken for those assignments  was time that you could have spent on other subjects. It didn't really filter out much of anyone and only led to some people requiring an extra semester of attendance.

The third variation was a participation requirement. The course was held at 8 am and the materials necessary for passing were not online and only shown/explained for those present. Taking notes and paying attention during the entirety of the course was 100% necessary for passing. It instilled good habits and filtered out those that didn't take things seriously. A lot of the faces in that course vanished over the coming months since many found it difficult to uphold a constant attendance with good levels of concentration.

The fourth was simply a very challenging final exam. It filtered out a lot of students but it also led to the occasional student that simply skipped it for later and had 145 out of 150 credit points with the last 5 held hostage by some basic course held in the first semester.

I did meet and know of many students that have been filtered out by one or the other so it did work but it also always ended up either wasting time or largely inconvenient to other able students.

Comment: It's not clear to me that that first variation of a filter course was actually a filter course. It might very well just have been a bad teacher.

Comment: I don't know that Germany is a good comparison, since Germany already does a lot of pre-filtering of unprepared students that the US doesn't do. I started to say "Doesn't Germany start filtering at age 14-16?" but then I found a [description of the German educational system](https://www.studying-in-germany.org/german-education-system/) which seems to indicate that the filtering starts at age 9, determining which sort of secondary school a student attends, which filters out those who won't even go to university.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer (+1).  It is important for lecturers to ensure that a filter course is still a course of good quality and substance --- the filtering effect should come from the inherent challenge of the material, not any artificially introduced deficiencies in teaching.

Comment: @shoover It's true that there is a whole lot of filtering going on depending on which schools you visited in your younger years but universities still have filter courses in their first semesters. That is mainly because no matter what school you ended up in your younger years, if you wish to attend a university, the means to do so are provided for you. Because of that, it's not uncommon to see students that are 30+ years old on campus.

Comment: @Squary94 Good to know. I don't know whether you have any experience with US institutions, but if you don't, you might be surprised at the lack of preparedness of some of the admitted students, accompanied in many cases by a lack of self-awareness regarding their unpreparedness. Also, US institutions vary widely in their selectivity, with some admitting all comers and others only the top 5% of applicants.   Hence the need for filter/weeder courses.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, your premise that a course in linear algebra would act primarily as a filter ---as opposed to being something that is substantively important in data science--- seems dubious to me.  In any case, there are probably a number of general mathematics courses that could act simultaneously as a valuable substantive course and also a "filter" on progression to later stages of the program.

One of the things you will notice in any university program, and which can easily be confirmed by the empirical data on student grades within the program, is that the grades of each student are highly correlated across different courses in the same program (i.e., a student who does well in one course is more likely to also do well in another course, and *vice versa*).  Thus, failure/success in a filter course may indeed be a reasonable predictor of results in later courses.  For any university department considering this issue, it ought to be possible to get a historical record of student grades in their courses in order to undertake empirical assessment of the extent to which success in one course is predictive of success in another (or of overall success in the program).

A secondary thing to note here is the "gatekeeping" function is not limited solely to an initial filter course.  The entire process of grading students and passing/failing them acts as a filtering function throughout the entire program.  When course lecturers are too lenient in their grading for a course, this has the averse effect of allowing weak students to progress to higher-level courses, which in turn causes difficulties and frustrations for the lecturers of those later courses.  Consequently, appropriate attention to prerequisites and marking standards is something that should be applied throughout the entire program, not just by setting up a filter course at the start.

> Do filter courses really do what they set out to do and produce stronger majors at the end of the program?  Or would including such a course in a major's curriculum potentially be a waste of valuable course time that could be better utilized elsewhere in the program?

Since course marks are correlated for by student, any prerequisite course at the start of a program is likely to succeed in filtering out students who are likely to do poorly on later courses.  Some students may come into a program as weak students (e.g., ill-prepared, poor aptitude in the subject matter, etc.).  Many of these may be able to develop into stronger students if they have additional time in their degree program, which is something that sometimes occurs when a student initially fails a filter course and then repeats the course.  I disagree with the other answer here that raises alleged equity problems with this function --- so long as it sets a single objective standard for all students, it is not problematic that some students come into the program less prepared than others, and are therefore less likely to pass through the filter.  Indeed, the entire function of the filter course is to ensure that students meet some minimum objective standard in the course before proceeding to the remainder of the program.

Here it is notable that a filter course can also provide remedial education, particularly if you use a general mathematics course as your filter course.  Consequently, the course can operate both as a filter and as a means of upskilling students who are insufficiently prepared to pass in the first instance.  (In a previous academic role I worked in, we gave incoming students a short mathematics test that tested material from their pre-university schooling courses; students who failed this test were required to take remedial sessions to assist them prior to the start of the regular semester.  This was not a "filter" per se, but it had a similar effect in identifying weak students and giving them some preliminary remedial attention.)  The Department might wish to allow students to attempt the filter course multiple times, to give poorly-prepared students the opportunity to use it as remedial education and then proceed past the filter once they meet the minimum requirements.  Whether or not a filter course of this kind is beneficial enough to warrant the opportunity cost of displacing another course depends on the extent to which the Department is having difficulties with the quality of students in the program.